# Murnaghan Nakayama rule and the character of the young orthogonal form representation matrices

Tags: matrices

Is the Murnaghan Nakayama character formula also the character of the Young orthogonal form representation of the symmetric group matrices corresponding to the Coxeter generators of the form (i,i+1)?
Many thanks

Comment: I am dubious as to what the character in the Murnaghan Nakayama rule stands for

Comment: This is not a _Mathematica_ question.

Comment: You do realize people might not know everything. Please consider representing the problem in a known mathematical form instead of jargons. Pictures and codes can help too.